# Extracting specific text from textarea between two words via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a simple jquery code, which can output the text written between "Reference Code:" and "Mineral". So the output text should be "12345 asdf".
Please take a look at my code which can output all the text after "Reference Code:" but it is not working output to only "Mineral" word.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class='txt' id='txt'>
Name and formula
Reference code: 12345
asdf
Mineral name:   Periclase
</textarea>

<h3 id="firstLine"></h3>

<script>
var lines = $('#txt').val().split('code:');
    var outPut=lines[1];
    $("#firstLine").html(outPut)
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex

Breakdown

```
/code:\s+        // starts with literal code: and whitespace, here a tab
([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)  // capture alphabetics, digits and dash
\s+?Mineral/     // until the literal Mineral with a possible leading whitespace
```

NOTE the textarea has newlines and tabs

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class='txt' id='txt'>
Name and formula

Reference code: 0N-NNN-YYYY 

Mineral name:   Periclase 
Compound name:  Magnesium Oxide 
</textarea>

<h3 id="firstLine"></h3>

<script>
const code = $('#txt').val().match(/code:\s+([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\s+?Mineral/m);
    $("#firstLine").html(code ? code[1] : "not found")
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir, but if textarea value is "Reference code: 12345 hello", even then it is only output 12345. I want that how many words of line if befire Mineral word then it should out all those words of lines.

Comment: sir I have updated my question a little, added "asdf" in the next line. so it should output "12345 asdf".

Comment: Sir, there is one more problem in this, if I replace "code:" to "formula" then it should show "Reference code: 12345 whatever". or if I replace "code:" to "Reference" then it should show "code: 12345 whatever". But it is not working like that.

Comment: I think it is not showing because of a special character. but I don't know how to add it in that

Comment: Show actual data please, then I can look

Comment: Sir, I do have a file which include many values, I want to extract these values and peak list table into the website page. Please look at my file,

https://k00.fr/ur9vmim7

Comment: If possible, please also share some video or good tutorial from where I can understand about "regex".

Comment: Also I think, adding "Peak list" table into website page would be very difficult. Can you please show an example for for that also. It would be very kind of your sir.

Comment: You had a tab and dashes. I changed the code

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "peak list  table"

Comment: Here is a great resource for regex: https://regex101.com/r/I1jEuZ/1